# Optional features settings are blank

Tags: windows-10, display

I was trying to use my laptop as a monitor for my main pc. When I went to the project this pc section in settings, it was greyed out:
[image]

So I found out that you need to go into the optional features and add a feature. But when I go there, it is blank.
[image: Image 2]

I tried going to the same place on my pc, but it is blank on my pc and laptop. The pc and laptop is my work computer, but the only limitations I have is that I am not admin on any. Am am running windows 10 home on both too. The weird part is that when I try the same thing on win pro, it works. This shouldn't be a windows 10 home problem, right?

Comment: Your WinSxS directory is corrupt, time to do an in-place repair.  You will need your IT Administrator to perform that action on your work PC

Comment: What action? I can temporarily get admin rights and fix it if I know what to do. I am comfortable with using cmd and anything else I need to do.

Comment: You will be unable to solve this particular problem if you are not an Administrator.  **You should contact your IT Administrator for assistance with this problem**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I finally figured it out. **The features are only shown if you are logged in as admin.** So that is why it was showing in my VM because I was an admin. Thanks anyway.

Comment: OMG I'm a tech of 10yr & I've spent hours trying to install RSAT from an ISO yet THIS was the easy fix & cause! Wish Microsoft would flippin document this in [RSAT download page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520)!